# Alter a line of code by date?

Tags: c#

I have a function that builds a reservation viewer for public view by drawing upon a query from a scheduling application. We have a time discrepancy somewhere in the system that is causing event times to be presented as one hour later than intended (ignoring daylight savings time). The following addition fixes it .AddHours(-1), but now I need a script that will remove the .AddHours() piece at midnight on November 4th, 2018, and then put it back at midnight, March 10th, 2019. By then, I expect we'll have updated the affected systems. Anybody know how I can do this easily?

```
}
reservationRow["EventStartTime"] = Convert.ToDateTime(r25EventStartDate.InnerText).AddHours(-1).ToString("hh:mm tt");
reservationRow["EventEndTime"] = Convert.ToDateTime(r25EventEndDate.InnerText).AddHours(-1).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: Whenever there is a built in way to do things one shall never reinvent the wheel. DateTimeOffset/UTC Time/Time stamp was invented just for issues like this.

Comment: So would you change the above code to incorporate Offset, Now, or UTC? When I try, I'm getting errors regarding System.Convert not containing definitions for these. BTW, I'm a rookie at this.

Comment: when you store the time don't store it as DateTime. Use either UTC or Timestamp. You should be fixing it right at the database level instead of trying to hotfix it here

Comment: I replaced "Convert.ToDateTime" with DateTimeOffset.Parse" and removed the "AddHours(-1)" and it works well. Thanks for the comments/advice.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
reservationRow["EventStartTime"] = Convert.ToDateTime(r25EventStartDate.InnerText).AddHours(-1).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

with

```
reservationRow["EventStartTime"] = DateTimeOffset.Parse(r25EventStartDate.InnerText).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

and it works fine. Thanks for the advice/comments.